# Problem with teleporting Player to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 levels in my game, and the Door object to teleport player to another level(colliding with the door). The problem is that when i enter my door in some specific way(just moving forward without stopping), player teleports right to the third level. I think that is because OverlapCollider function detects some extra hits. How do i fix it? Here is my code and screenshot.

**Door**

```
public class Door : Collidable
{
    public string[] sceneNames;

    private static int sceneNumber = 0;

    protected override void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if(coll.name == "Player")
        {
            GameManager.instance.SaveState();

            //Teleport the player to next level
            sceneNumber++;

            if (sceneNumber >= sceneNames.Length)
            {
                return;
            }

            string sceneName = sceneNames[sceneNumber];
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Collidable**

```
public class Collidable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ContactFilter2D filter;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Collider2D[] hits = new Collider2D[10];

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        //Collision work
        boxCollider.OverlapCollider(filter,hits);
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hits[i] == null)
                continue;

            OnCollide(hits[i]);

            //The array is not cleaned up, so we do it ourself
            hits[i] = null; 
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollide(Collider2D coll) 
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollide was not implemented in " + this.name);
    }
}
```

[Door and player colliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUFdG.png)

I tried to minimize door collider size, but it didnt work. I thought some extra hits appear because player collider is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to load the next scene by utilizing the [build index](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-buildIndex.html).

```csharp
protected override void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
{
    if(coll.name == "Player")
    {
        GameManager.instance.SaveState();
        SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter how many times the collision occurs, it will always load the following scene. You only have to make sure that you've added your scenes in the correct order and that the last scene doesn't try to execute this code.